# Aligning the image inside the text to fit the text

Tags: html, css

How can we position the coin so that it fits the text? So far as you see the coin is a bit upper than the median line of the text.

```css
.coins_plans {
   font-size: 1rem;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}

.coins_plans img {
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<p class="coins_plans">all <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d6/Gold_coin_icon.png"> s you got till now. </p>
```

Here is what I want:

[image]

Comment: `width: auto;
    height: 1em;` for the image?

Comment: Not working.....

Comment: share a screenshot of the result you want

Comment: updated.........

Comment: vertical-align: middle; to image

Comment: That's it... Thanks close voters ;)